# Getting LibGDX to work in Eclipse

Tags: android, html, eclipse, libgdx

So I've been trying to install libgdx for a few days with Eclipse and it kept telling me various things (Android ADT, Java JDK, etc.) needed to be updated, so I did that, but I kept getting the same error.

Then I decided to download an older version [(0.9.8)](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/releases/) and I used the gdx-setup-ui.jar to set up my projects. But upon opening them in the Eclipse/ADT bundle, the Android and HTML projects had errors in them involving the import statements, which I tried to solve to no avail.

[This](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/09/19/LibGDX-Tutorial-1-Creating-an-initial-project.aspx) is the tutorial I've mainly tried to follow.

Does anybody have a solution for me to get it to work? I'm most familiar with Eclipse, having worked with it for Android for a while now, so I'd prefer not to switch IDEs.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Use ADT (Android Developer Tools) instead of Eclipse. (Is the same thing anyways)

http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html

If you got errors after importing your projects on android, right click on the android project, and at android, check the version that is there.

For HTML you need to install the GWT plugin.
Recently libGDX has moved to Gradle, so you might want to look over that
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle